# ctags doesn't find all gtk methods

Tags: linux, gtk, ctags

I want to create a complete list of tags for gtk-3.0.

So I tried it with

```
ctags -R --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS /usr/include/gtk-3.0/
```

It works, but the list is incomplete. e.g. gtk_file_chooser_dialog_new is missing, but I definitely can see it in /usr/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtkfilechooserdialog.h:

```
GtkWidget *gtk_file_chooser_dialog_new (const gchar *title,
              GtkWindow            *parent,
              GtkFileChooserAction  action,
              const gchar          *first_button_text,
              ...) G_GNUC_NULL_TERMINATED;
```

So I tried with this file only, and there is still no gtk_file_chooser_dialog_new to be found:

```
ctags --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS /usr/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtkfilechooserdialog.h
```

And this is generated:
https://gist.github.com/3879327

thanks in advance, kulpae

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would actually recommend trying [GNU global](http://www.gnu.org/software/global/) as a compatible replacement for ctags/etags. I started using it after finding similar disappointing results much like you are describing. I tested against a gtk-3.0.12 tarball:

```
$ cd gtk+-3.0.12
$ gtags
$ global gtk_file_chooser_dialog_new
gtk/gtkfilechooserdialog.c
```

The documentation shows [examples for supported editors](http://www.gnu.org/software/global/globaldoc_toc.html) for browsing the objects from the code base. A quick version with `less` would look like this:

```
$ export LESSGLOBALTAGS=global
$ less -t gtk_file_chooser_dialog_new
```

Answer (score 2):

Ctags ignores the method declaration because of several GTK macros.

Passing the arguments to ignore them fixes the problem:

```
ctags -R --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS -I G_GNUC_NULL_TERMINATED -I G_GNUC_CONST  -f gtk3 /usr/include/gtk-3.0/
```

There are probably more of them, so this list is not complete, but it adds extra 418 symbols.